# glyph-icon size within a tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

http://jsfiddle.net/r9dunwzs/1/

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">one</a></li>
      <li>
          <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="font-size: 25px"></i>
         </a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in jsFiddle, I'm having problems to increase the font size of an icon within a tab in bootstrap 3.

The expected behaviour is the following:

[image]

but when I increase the font-size my tabs get deformed:

[image]

How can I increase the glyph-icon size without deforming my tabs ?

Comment: beware of padding - .nav > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
}  . Try to reduce the padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the a href of the icon and set a new line-height to the icon

**HTML**

```
<div class="bs-docs-example">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">one</a></li>
      <li>
          <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" class="bicon">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="font-size: 25px"></i>
         </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a.bicon{ padding: 0px 6px !important;

}

a.bicon i{ line-height: 1.45em !important;

}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/r9dunwzs/2/)**

Comment: It gets it closer, but when I view it the tab with the glyphicon is ever so slightly raised from the bottom "bar" of the tab pane; there's a slight gap.

Comment: You need to adjust the padding and/or the line-height. If not, can you upload a image to see where is that gap? Hmmm...on hover there is a gap, try this: line-height: 1.55em

Comment: @LuisP.A. http://jsfiddle.net/r9dunwzs/4/, I just did it.. thanks Luis, give you the answer cause it was really helpful.